# How to turn off Windows 7 Automatic Updates?

Tags: windows-7, automatic-update

I'm using Windows 7 Enterprise and I need to turn off the Automatic Updates feature, but don't know how.

The "Change Automatic Updates Setting" has been deactivated with a greyed out look, as seen in the attached screen capture:

[image]

Comment: are you part of a domain?

Comment: Yeah, that yellow notification at the tops looks like it'd be the "some settings are managed by your system administrator" message you see if some/all of the settings are enforced by Group Policy (for example.)

Comment: Hi, soandos, Yes

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yeah, you are on a domain. You'll need to have a chat with who ever sets the Group policy in your Domain.

I have the same thing **and** I have domain privileges.

[image]

Comment: +1, it could even be as simple as moving the PC into or out of an OU in AD.

Comment: Then again, it's not like Windows 7 needs **constant** updates. The only ones we bother to push out are the security ones rated **critical**. I actually spend more time tinkering with the Adobe Flash admin kit.  They seem to push out security updates like every other day.  Flash actually scares me more than the OS currently.

Comment: Can the related services be disabled? BITS and Windows Update services.

Comment: If you are in a domain, that would annoy the admin.

Comment: Its also a horrible idea.  Windows 7 might be secure, its not perfect, just like how Mac OS X isn't perfect.  Both need to be patched...

Answer (score 0):

```
Type: “regedit”
Hit Enter
```

Go to:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU

Find AUOptions. You can change the values from 1 through 5.

```
1. Download updates but let me choose whether to install them
2. Check for updates but let me choose whether to download and install them
3. Download updates but let me choose whether to install them
4. Install updates automatically
5. Enable the option box to choose manually
```

(source http://mkncreations.com/site/2012/09/fix-windows-7-update-settings-disabled-grayed-out/)